# Nest JS & TypeORM cannot use findOne properly

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to get a user instance based on `id` (same happens for other attributes such as `email`. Inside the Service, this is my code:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  @InjectRepository(User)
  private readonly repository: Repository<User>;

  async findOne(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.repository.findOne(id);
    return user;
  }
}
```

and my User entity is:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 120 })
  public name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 120 })
  public email: string;
}
```

The problem is that I always get this error:
`src/api/user/user.service.ts - error TS2559: Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'FindOneOptions<User>'.`

Other methods such as `getAll` work just fine:

```js
public getAllUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
  return this.repository.find();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

are you using the latest version of `typeorm`? Then downgrade it to `typeorm@0.2` because `@nestjs/typeorm@8.0` might not support the latest one yet. You can read the changes of `typeorm@0.3` here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0

Answer (score 10):

There are some breaking changes in `typeorm`. I wouldn't suggest downgrading, instead check the latest methods.

`findOne(id);`
is now changed to

```
findOneBy({
id: id // where id is your column name
})
```

And `find()` is now

```
find({
  select: {
    id: true,
    email: true,
    password: true,
  },
});
```

Please check [this link](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0) for more information.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. The approach is mentioned in the change log https://typeorm.io/changelog#features-4

Comment: What if I have nested entity. Something like-
`select: { client: { user: true } }`
This thing does not work in latest version. Is there any solution?

Comment: @Srk95 I think you need to use the `where` in the docs https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0.   For example `userRepository.find({
    where: {
        photos: {
            album: {
                name: "profile"
            }
        }
    }
})`

Comment: @SananAli `select` clause and `where` clause are different. I want to have the nested structure under `select` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you don't need to downgrade the `typeorm` package. Just changed to `findOne` by this:

```
async findOne(id: number): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.repository.findOne({
           where: { id }
    });
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

findOne(id) signature was dropped. Use following syntax instead:

```
const user = await userRepository.findOneBy({
    id: id // where id is your column name
})
```

According to the latest version of Typeorm, findOne expression has been changed as above.

Answer (score 0):

check-in your `package.json` file and replace your version of typeorm with this one `"typeorm": "^0.2.34"`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the typeorm version , try typeorm version 0.2.25 and it will be works